# How can I use the until function with appropriate way

Tags: perl

I have a file that I want to filter which is like that:

```
##matrix=axtChain 16 91,-114,-31,-123,-114,100,-125,-31,-31,-125,100,-114,-123,-31,-114,91
##gapPenalties=axtChain O=400 E=30
chain 21455232 chr20 14302601 + 37457 14119338 chr22 14786829 + 3573 14759345 1
189     159     123
24      30      22
165     21      20
231     105     0
171     17      19
261     0       2231
222     2       0
253     56      48

chain 164224 chr20 14302601 + 1105938 1125118 chr22 14786829 + 1081744 1100586 8
221     352     334
24      100     112
34      56      56
26      50      47
…………………….
chain 143824 chr20 14302601 + 1105938 1125118 chr22 14786829 + 1081744 1100586 8
```

So, briefly,there are blocks separated by a blank line.
Each block begins with the line " chain xxxxx " and continues with lines with numbers.
I want to filter out the file and keep just the blocks with chain and the number that follows be greater than 3000.
I wrote the following script to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX;

my $chain = $ARGV[0];

#It filters the chains with chains >= 3000.
open my $chain_file, $chain or die "Could not open $chain: $!";

my @array;
while( my $cline = <$chain_file>)  {
    #next if /^\s*#/;
    chomp $cline;
    #my @lines = split (/ /, $cline);
    if ($cline =~/^chain/) {
        my @lines = split (/\s/, $cline);
        if ($lines[1] >= 3000) {
            #print $lines[1];
            #my @lines = split (/ /, $cline);

            #print "$cline\n";
            push (@array, $cline);
        }
    }
    until ($cline ne ' ') {
        push (@array, $cline);
    }


    foreach (@array) {
        print "$_\n";

    }
    undef(@array);
}
```

The problem is that I can print just the headers (chain XXXXX…..) and not the numbers that follows at the next lines of each block.
I'm using the until function till will find the blank line, but it doesn't work.
If someone could help me with that….
Thank you very much in advance,
Vasilis.

Comment: `$cline ne ' '` is not a way to check for a blank line. It is a way to check if the line is exactly one space or not. `until` is just the negation of `while`, so it has no special power, and it cannot be used there, because the `while` statement assigns to `$cline`.

Comment: Thank you very much,
So what do you propose me to use?

Comment: If you have a manageable size on your records, you can use paragraph mode to read them. Then you can split the records on newline. Setting the input record separator to the empty string will enable paragraph mode.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it with your way. I believe than now it works. I will check it a little bit more, but I believe that now its ok Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem here is that `'  '` is a single space, not a blank line (`""` or `''` should be fine since you've already `chomp`-ed the line.

The second problem is that

```
until ( $cline ne "" )
```

is the same as

```
while ( $cline eq "" )
```

which is the opposite of what you need to push lines to `@array`.

That said, the flip-flop operator is probably a more suitable construct for what you're after:

```
my @array;
while ( <$chain_file> ) {          # Using $_ instead of $cline

    chomp;

    if ( do { /^chain\s+(\d+)/ && $1 >= 3000 } .. /^$/ ) {

                                   # Accumulate lines in @array
        push @array, $_;           # False until LHS evaluates to true ...
    }                              # ... then true until RHS evaluates to true

    else {
        for ( @array ) {
          print $_, "\n";          # Print matches
        }
        @array = ();               # Reset/clear out @array
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I will put the restriction of the 3000 if I cann' t split each "chain" line to take the score?

Comment: @Vasilis : The LHS conditional can be updated as shown in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best not to use `unless` instead of `while`.  It negates the boolean expression many times leaving you with a double negative to solve. Here's an example

```
 while ( $foo ne $bar ) {
```

Even though this is a negative expression, I can pretty easily figure out when to exit my loop. However:

```
until ( $foo eq $bar ) {
```

Just takes time to figure out.

Also,  '  ' does not make a blank line: Use the regular expression `$cline  =~ /^\s*$/`. However, even beyond that the loop:

```
until ($cline ne ' ') {
    push (@array, $cline);
}
```

will go on forever if `$cline` does equal blank. You're never changing the value of `$cline`.

You can use what I use to call *state variables* (until Perl actually created a variable type called [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) and now I have no idea what to call them.) This variable tracks where you are in your file. Are you inside a chain section of the file? Do you want these lines or not? This way, you only have a single loop. You set your *state* variables and then process your loop.

In this example, I have a *state* variable called `$keep_line` which is asking whether or not I want to keep the lines I want to read in. If the line starts with `chain` and the second field is greater than 3000, I want to keep the entire block (if I understand what you're attempting to do). (By the way, I'm keeping blank lines. Is that okay?)

```
my $keep_lines = 0;   # Aren't in lines I want to keep
my @good_lines;       # Array where you want to keep the good lines

while ( my $line = <$chain_file> ) {
     chomp $line;                   # Good habit to always chomp a input as soon as it's read.
     if ( $line =~ /^chain/ ) {     # This is a chain line. Do I want to keep this group?
          my @fields =  ( /\s+/, $line );
         if ( $field[1] > 3000 ) {  # Yes, if the second field is greater than 3000
             $keep_lines = 1;       # Keep this and all other lines until the next chain line
         }
         else {
             $keep_lines = 0;       # Skip until the next chain line
         }
     }
     if ( $keep_lines ) {
         push @good_lines, $line;
     }
}
```

I also smell a function here: Instead of the tangle of `if` clauses, I would probably make this a function that returns the value I set `$keep_lines` to.

```
while ( my $line = <$chain_file> ) {
     chomp $line;                   # Good habit to always chomp a input as soon as it's read.
     $keep_lines = keep_this_section( $line );
     if ( $keep_lines ) {
         push @good_lines, $line;
     }
}
```

Simplifies the code quite a bit.

I would also declare some constants to remove those *Mysterious Moes*. Those are things like `3000` and `/^chain/` that have some sort of mysterious, but important meaning in your program. You can `use constant` as a pragma to define Perl constants. It's part of standard Perl:

```
use constant {
    KEEP_LIMIT       => 3000,
    SECTION_HEADER   => qr/^chain/,
};
```

Now, I can do things like this:

```
if ( $line =~ SECTION_HEADER ) {
```

instead of:

```
if ( $line =~ /^chain/ ) {
```

and

```
if ( $field[1] > KEEP_LIMIT ) {
```

instead of

```
if ( $field[1] > 3000 ) {
```

There are problems with the [constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) pragma. The biggest is that it just doesn't interpolate in places where Perl will normally interpolate variables. This include double quoted strings and hash keys. If I have `$foo{KEEP_LIMIT}`, Perl will interpret the key as  a string `KEEP_LIMIT` and not as a constant of `KEEP_LIMIT`.

Many developers use [Readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Readonly) which is just so much better in so many ways. Unfortunately, `Readonly` isn't a standard Perl module, so you have to install it via CPAN, and that's sometimes not possible or desirable to do. So, I tend to use `constant`.